# LPC18S37 - AES engine encrypts differently than Python library

Tags: python, c, encryption, aes, lpc

I am trying to use the AES engine of the LPC18S37 in ECB-mode to encrypt a 16-bytes plaintext. I obtain a ciphertext, which I then take through the decryption process to verify that I get the same original plaintext, which I do.

However, as a safety measure, I also desired to verify using an external resource, and therefore encrypted the same plaintext using a Python API (Crypto.Cipher.AES) in ECB-mode) but I didn't get the same ciphertext as from the MCU. The problem is that when I decrypt the Python version of the ciphertext, result is the same original plaintext.

I verified the lib's algorithm implementation, comparing it to the FIPS-197 standard : It is properly implemented.

I therefore assume that the problem most likely comes from my implementation of the code in the MCU.

I took of course care of verifying that the keys and plaintexts were strictly the same in both scenarios.

If anybody has advices or knows how to solve the problem, I would gladly welcome any ideas.

Here are the relevant parts of the implementation of the MCU program :

```
Board_Init();

Chip_AES_Init();

//Set buffers :
        uint8_t RX_plaintext[16]; / /Contains a 16-bytes plaintext
        uint8_t TX_plaintext[16]; // WILL contain a 16-bytes plaintext after decryption
        uint8_t RX_key[16]; // Contains a 16-bytes key
        uint8_t TX_ciphertext[16]; // WILL contain the 16-bytes ciphertext after encryption

         ...

Chip_AES_LoadKeySW((uint8_t *) RX_key); // I like using verbose casts but this works the same way even without them

Chip_AES_SetMode(CHIP_AES_API_CMD_ENCODE_ECB);
Chip_AES_Operate((uint8_t *)TX_ciphertext, (uint8_t *)RX_plaintext, 1);

Chip_AES_SetMode(CHIP_AES_API_CMD_DECODE_ECB);
Chip_AES_Operate((uint8_t *)TX_plaintext, (uint8_t *)TX_ciphertext, 1);
```

And the Python part (version 3.8.2) :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import numpy as np

...

t_plaintext = np.random.randint(0, 255, size = 16, dtype = np.uint8)
t_key = np.random.randint(0, 255, size = 16, dtype = np.uint8)

...

o_cryptoEngine = AES.new(bytes(t_key), AES.MODE_ECB)

t_AES_by_Python = np.frombuffer(o_cryptoEngine.encrypt(bytes(t_plaintext)),dtype=np.uint8)
t_decryption_by_Python = np.frombuffer(o_cryptoEngine.decrypt(bytes (t_AES_by_Python)),dtype=np.uint8)
```

As the key and plaintext are generated randomly, the output changes everytime but is never identical between MCU and Python. Again though, decryption goes back to the same identical original plaintext.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you also post equivalent python code? Please, tell also python version, you are using. Also outputs from both would be helpful. Please also provide key, so it is possible to reproduce.

Comment: Your datatype is already `uint8_t *`, no need to cast anything in your c code.

Comment: Python code and version have been edited in :) As mentionned, output changes each build though, as key and plaintext are generated randomly

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it :-)

If anyone encounters a similar problem someday : it had to do with the way data was processed by the AES engine. The array was processed from the opposite sides between the MCU (which had a hardware AES engine) and the Python script (which had a software implementation).

The way the data is processed can't be changed, so flipping the key and plaintext buffers before processing by the MCU and the flipping them again after encryption did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use known test vectors to see, which algorithm is wrong.

https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/aes/KAT_AES.zip

E.g. there are know tests for AES CBC 128

```
KEY = 10a58869d74be5a374cf867cfb473859
PLAINTEXT = 00000000000000000000000000000000
CIPHERTEXT = 6d251e6944b051e04eaa6fb4dbf78465
```

Equivalent python implementation

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = bytearray.fromhex('10a58869d74be5a374cf867cfb473859')
cipher = AES.new(bytes(key), AES.MODE_ECB)
plaintext = bytearray.fromhex('00000000000000000000000000000000')
print(cipher.encrypt(bytes(plaintext)).hex())
# will print '6d251e6944b051e04eaa6fb4dbf78465' so it is correct
```

You can do the same for C to see if it is wrong or you are using it wrong.

```c
uint8_t key[16] = {0x10, 0xa5, 0x88, 0x69, 0xd7, 0x4b, 0xe5, 0xa3, 0x74, 0xcf, 0x86, 0x7c, 0xfb, 0x47, 0x38, 0x59};
uint8_t plaintext[16] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
uint8_t ciphertext[16] = {};
uint8_t expected_ciphertext[16] = {0x6d, 0x25, 0x1e, 0x69, 0x44, 0xb0, 0x51, 0xe0, 0x4e, 0xaa, 0x6f, 0xb4, 0xdb, 0xf7, 0x84, 0x65};

Chip_AES_Init();
Chip_AES_LoadKeySW(key);
Chip_AES_SetMode(CHIP_AES_API_CMD_ENCODE_ECB);
Chip_AES_Operate(ciphertext, plaintext, 1);

if(memcmp(ciphertext, expected_ciphertext, 16) != 0) {
   // LPC implementation is wrong and is not compliant
}
```

You can also use [mbedtls](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls) instead of crappy functions provided by LPC.